# QGIS Layout - Add image in attribute table

Tags: pyqgis

I am creating a layout of map using QGIS 3.10
I want to show attribute table with each point logo in table.
I have a field which has the complete path to each logo and this field is already being used in symbology to show each respective college logo.e.g. in below picture attribute table is shown and in `pic_path` column instead of actual path I want logo to be shown.

[image]